# Moving Geometry by Centroid

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I have a collection of points:

`[[2000,3000], [2000,12000], [10000,120000], [10000,3000], [2000,3000]]`

and it has a center at coordinates `[6000, 7500]`

What is a way to shift all the coordinates  around a new center `[x_new, y_new]`?  Example, if I wanted to shift all the x/y's around `[0,0]` instead of the current center but I want to retain the shape.

The shapes vertices are not always rectangles, I am just using that for a simple example.

I want to limit 3rd party modules to numpy and the standard python library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting a group of points in lockstep is achieved by adding the same displacement vector to each of them.

This is easy using numpy

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[2000,3000], [2000,12000], [10000,120000], [10000,3000], [2000,3000]])
com = np.mean(points, axis=0)
delta = np.array((0, 0)) - com
shifted_points = points + delta
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I was trying to use affine transformations to do this, but it wasn't working out well for me.. This is way easier.

Comment: Rotation and skewing are my next geometric tasks I want to accomplish!

Comment: You'll have to look into rotation matrices `np.array([[np.cos(r), np.sin(r)], [-np.sin(r), np.cos(r)]])` and skewing matrices `np.array([[1, s], [0, 1]])` for that. Good luck! P.S.: If you want to combine it all you may want to come back to affine transformations in the end.